# Why colorRampPalette produces NAs?

Tags: r

I have the following list

```
  t <- c(22, 22, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 18, 
    18, 18, 12, 12, 12, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 20, 20, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 17, 17, 17, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15)
```

which I want to assign color for each uniform color with this code

```
library(RColorBrewer)
rowcol <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"))
rowcol(length(unique(t)))[t]
```

But why it produces NAs?

```
 [1] NA        NA        "#A66F20" "#A66F20" "#A66F20" "#A66F20" "#A66F20" "#A66F20" "#A66F20" "#A66F20" "#A66F20"
 [12] "#578A52" "#578A52" "#578A52" "#578A52" "#578A52" "#578A52" "#578A52" "#8A6C8D" "#8A6C8D" "#8A6C8D" "#C9611D"
 [23] "#C9611D" "#C9611D" "#1B9E77" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D"
 [34] "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#93762D" "#7F6EA0" "#7F6EA0"
 [45] "#7F6EA0" "#7F6EA0" "#7F6EA0" "#7F6EA0" "#7F6EA0" "#7F6EA0" "#7F6EA0" "#7F6EA0" "#7F6EA0" "#7F6EA0" "#7F7C39"
 [56] "#7F7C39" "#7F7C39" "#7F7C39" "#7F7C39" NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
 [67] NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        "#7570B3" "#7570B3" "#BB6814" "#BB6814"
 [78] "#BB6814" "#BB6814" "#BB6814" "#BB6814" "#BB6814" "#BB6814" "#BB6814" "#BB6814" "#D35F0B" "#D35F0B" "#D35F0B"
 [89] "#D35F0B" "#D35F0B" "#D35F0B" "#D35F0B" "#D35F0B" "#D35F0B" "#D35F0B" "#D35F0B" "#D35F0B" "#D35F0B" "#D35F0B"
[100] "#D35F0B" "#2F976A" "#2F976A" "#2F976A" "#43905E" "#43905E" "#43905E" "#43905E" "#6B8345" "#6B8345" "#6B8345"
[111] "#6B8345" "#6B8345" "#CE6208" "#CE6208" "#CE6208" "#946A7B" "#946A7B" "#946A7B" "#B46543" "#B46543" "#A96755"
[122] "#A96755" "#A96755"
```

At the end of the day I'd like to use this final vector as `RowSideColors` argument in `heatmap.2`.

Comment: Try `rowcol(max(t))[t]`

Comment: And "t" is not strictly a list (R speaking). It is a vector.

Answer (score 4):

Let's use your vector "t":

What is the length of `unique(t)`?

```
length(unique(t))
# 20
```

What happens if we use `rowcol`:

```
pal <- rowcol(length(unique(t)))
pal
#  [1] "#1B9E77" "#61864B" "#A66F20" "#CE6014" "#A96755" "#846D97" "#8D61AA" "#B7469B" "#E12C8C" "#BE5067" "#8E7E40"
# [12] "#6CA61C" "#9BA812" "#CBA907" "#DBA206" "#C48F10" "#AC7B1A" "#957130" "#7D6B4B" "#666666"

length(pal)
# 20
```

And what is the maximum of "t", i.e.

```
max(t)
# 22
```

We clearly see that the length of `pal` and the maximum value of "t" mismatch. That is why when "t" is equal to 21 or 22, you get `NA`.

You need to use `rowcol(max(t))[t]`

Answer (score 1):

It's because:

```
length(unique(t))
#> [1] 20
max(t)
#> [1] 22
all(is.na(rowcol(length(unique(t)))[t]) == (t>20))
#> [1] TRUE
```

and it's not an error for the index to exceed the length of the vector it's indexing; R just returns NA's when the index (`t`) exceeds the object it's indexing (`rowcol(length(unique(t)))`)